# Environment variables not being loaded into app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

In rails 5, I used to create a file called `.env` in an app's root directory, add something like this to it:

```
MY_VARIABLE=1234
```

and access the variables inside the app with `ENV["MY_VARIABLE"]`

But in a rails 6 app I do so same thing and it returns `nil`. When I run `ENV` I see lots of environment variables, but none which were in `.env`.

I am not sure why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `spring stop` and restart your rails app. However, if that didn't work, I like to let you know that Rails 6 now supports multiple credentials. You can use the format below:

From your rails terminals, run `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`. This will create `credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key` file for you inside `/config` if you don't have one.

**Then you can put your credentials in a YAML file like this**

```
development:
  aws:
    access_key_id: 123
    secret_access_key: 345

production:
  aws:
    access_key_id: 1f3649fe-ebbd-11e9-81b4-2a2ae2dbcce4
    secret_access_key: 203060d3a5456fa6cd2da3c958001440
```

**You can fetch the credentials this way**

```
> Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws][:access_key_id]
#=> "123"
```

Then you can proceed to `bundle install` and run `rails server`

You can read up from this [link](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html) on how you can fetch your credentials.